# Как найти нужные стили в WordPress?

Tags: css, wordpress

Порой кажется, что разработчики тем для ВП соревнуются между собой в запутанности тем.

Хочется изменить два банальных параметра - ширину тела сайта и ширину логотипа, ан нет! Нет таких параметров в style.css

Они инспектируются гуглом, четко указано, что есть такие стили и такие классы именно в этой папке и именно в этом файле. А их нет! Обычно я прощался с темой после подобного гемора, но в этот раз я решил разобраться с этим.

Одно смутило. В инспекции указаны и папка, и файл, но файл style.css идет с каким-то параметром, суть которого мне не ясна. То есть ссылается на файл такого вида: [https://сайт/wp-content/themes/тема/style.css?ver=4.9.4](https://%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82/wp-content/themes/%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0/style.css?ver=4.9.4)

Загадка. То же самое и с шириной тела сайта. Где искать этот параметр - известно только разрабам, а они не отвечают.

Comment: @SeVlad а так вопрос нужный, многие не понимают, как найти стили. Я тоже накатаю ответ часа через три.

Comment: Какие правила я нарушил?

Comment: Да вы никакие правила не нарушили. Насколько я понял @SeVlad, он имеет ввиду, что согласно правилам, надо отвечать по сути.

Comment: @KAGGDesign SeVlad имеет виду. что тело "вопроса" - нытьё ни о чем. Написано копирайтором, генерящим воду. Увлекательно но бесполезно. ОК. Кто-то всё же должен послать в  https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6688/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE-wordpress :)

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы понять, откуда берутся стили, надо кликнуть правой кнопкой на элементе и выбрать в меню "Просмотреть код". Откроется инспектор браузера (Development Tools).

Эти и дальнейшие инструкции предназначены для Chrome, поскольку он доминирует на рынке браузеров сегодня. В остальных браузерах ход инспекции примерно одинаков.

Допустим, мы решили проинспектировать заголовок главной страницы моего тестового сайта http://test.kagg.eu/

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Видим, что при открылась вкладка Elements инспектора с html кодом

```
<h2 class="entry-title">Home</h2>
```

Справа - стили этого элемента. При наведении на `style.css:1903` всплыла подсказка с полным url файла стилей: `http://test.kagg.eu/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/style.css`. Более того, указан номер строки в css, откуда взяты конкретные стили - 1903. Видим, что в строке 1903 находятся объявления правила для

```
.page .panel-content .entry-title, .page-title, body.page:not(.twentyseventeen-front-page) .entry-title
```

Обратите внимание на то, что сработали для данного элемента только те стили, что выделены чёрным `.page .panel-content .entry-title`. Те, что выделены серым, не применимы к данному элементу.

Прокручивая вниз правое окно стилей, можно увидеть, какие css-свойства работали на данном элементе. Перечёркнутые свойства не работают, они перекрыты в других правилах.

Для того, чтобы понять, откуда у данного элемента `Home` взялось то или иное свойство (например, font-family), кликните справа на вкладку Computed

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Видим, что `Libre Franklin` объявлен в строке 418 style.css. Надо навести курсор на style.css, чтобы узнать его полный url, поскольку файлов с таким именем может быть несколько.

Таким способом вы можете узнать, где объявлено любое свойство css: ширина body или ширина логотипа или что угодно ещё.

Касательно вашего вопроса о параметре `?ver=` в url файла стилей. Это всего лишь версия файла. Она задаётся либо явно в теме при вызове `wp_enqueue_style()`, либо принимает значение версии WordPress. Из вашего текста ясно, что у вас установлена последняя на настоящий момент версия WordPress 4.9.4.

Зачем вообще добавляют версию? Это имеет значение для кеширования. При смене `?ver=` браузер сбросит кеш этого файла, даже если в нём не изменили ни одного байта.

Но в целом это несколько другая тема, которую надо обсуждать отдельно. В рамках данного вопроса вы можете смело игнорировать `?ver=`. Да и в инспекторе этого параметра нет. Инспектор отображает текущую версию файла стилей.

**Update**

Что касается конкретной темы tdPersona, то ничего запутанного в ней нет.

Код функции `tdpersona_the_custom_logo()` находится в `wp-content/themes/tdpersona/inc/template-tags.php` -он очень простой, там 3 строчки, она вызывает стандартную функцию WordPress `the_custom_logo()`, а та вытаскивает размеры логотипа из базы, согласно настройкам в "Внешний вид->Настроить->Свойства сайта->Логотип". Пользуясь инструкцией выше, легко увидеть, что изображение логотипа обернуто в div с классом `.brand`. Чтобы изменить размер логотипа, достаточно добавить одно правило в style.css

```
.brand img {
    width: 200px;
}
```

Чтобы увидеть ширину "тела сайта, как вы это называете" (ширину контента, я полагаю), надо в инспекторе навести на `<header id="masthead" class="site-header container" role="banner">` и увидеть подсветку блока

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Справа внизу в окне стилей видим, что ширина контейнера задана в 31 строке файла style.css

```
.container {
    max-width: 940px;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ! Однако, все эти действия я знаю и делал. Покопавшись, я понял, что размеры логотипа прописаны в коде html, в атрибутах тега img. Но перерыв весь код, я нашел лишь небольшое упоминание в header.php в виде следующего запроса: <?php tdpersona_the_custom_logo(); ?>

Comment: Как можно понять, тема - TD Persona.

Comment: @Андрей я сомневаюсь, что вы знали указанные в ответе процедуры, иначе бы на самом первом шаге увидели, что размера прописаны в html коде элемента, и не стали бы в вопросе писать про style.css. Ну да ладно. Что вам мешает сейчас открыть код функции tdpersona_the_custom logo() и посмотреть, как она выводит изображение?

Comment: @Андрей кроме того, вы обошли молчанием тот момент, что мой ответ показывает, как найти ширину тела сайта (как вы это называете).

Comment: Зря сомневаетесь. Ответ как раз-таки находился в function.php, за эту наводку спасибо. Разве можно назвать решение вывода логотипа в виде функции адекватным? Ну, или рациональным? Я считаю, что нет.

Comment: Если в WordPress появилась возможность загрузки логотипа и функция для его вывода — решение воспользоваться ей представляется мне вполне адекватным и рациональным.