# Как в шаблоне wordpress в шапке задать картинке ссылку

Tags: html, css, wordpress

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать так, чтобы эта картинка была активной (при нажатии переходила на нужную ссылку)  (не понимаю где задать href)

Comment: Приведите интересующий вас фрагмент кода прямо в вопросе

Comment: Если бы я знал где фрагмент кода, который меня интересует, я бы смог самотоятельно вставить туда  href с ссылкой. Я прошу сказать, как это сделать, где искать, где исправлять (Редактор шаблона не работает, при попытки внести изменения например в style.css или functions.php через редактор - возникает ошибка, я так понимаю создатели шаблона так задумали)

Comment: Тогда скачайте тему на компьютер и найдите нужный фрагмент. Затем отредактируйте нужный файл в текстовом редакторе (как вам уже ответили, это, скорее всего, будет header.php) и залейте его на свой хостинг. Думаю, не стоит ждать более подробного ответа, так как, по сути, вы предлагаете гадать по фото.

Comment: @Oleksii это не создатели шаблона так задумали (тайну открою - невозможно), это у вас квалификации не хватает.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/798849/220220

Answer (score 0):

В папке темы ищите файл `header.php`. В нем и вносите правки