# Убрать стили на странице wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Скажите пожалуйста как убрать стили на странице view-source:https://mirinoi.by/
эти

Плагины все сразу отключил, стили не пропали

Comment: Как найти стили в WordPress? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/798707/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2-wordpress/798849#798849

Comment: Кроме того, непонятно, какие именно стили вы хотите убрать. "Плагины все сразу отключил" - ну, во-первых не все. Как минимум, вижу autooptimize, yoast seo, shutter reloaded plus. Во вторых, стили есть в вашей теме flatsome.

Comment: вроде разобрался, но откуда появляется тег <style scope="scope">

Comment: Скачайте сайт на локальный компьютер и запустите поиск по файлам. Лучше всего для этого использовать PhpStorm.

Comment: А можно как нибудь найти без загрузки на компьютер?

Comment: Практически нереально. Я работаю только так - локально все файлы, они синхронизированы с сервером. PhpStorm находит всё.

Comment: @razmenyairu можно искать и на сервере, имея доступ в консоль или в ФМ ПУ хостинга, если он это умеет. (ISP5 вроде умеет). Или сторонними скриптами. но осознавая, что это дыра (закрывать их от внешки и тд)