# Скрыть сайд бар для определенных типов постов

Tags: php, wordpress

Можно ли как то скрыть сайд бар для определенных типов постов? не искать в теме шаблона где есть вывод этого сайд бара, а просто дописать кусок кода

Comment: Сайдбар может быть сделан сотней способов. Без поиска кода - никак. Почитайте, как найти код в WP: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/798849/220220

Comment: Искать код сайт-бара нужно будет, без этого - только написать условие при подключение сайд-бара.

Answer (score 0):

В общем style.css можешь скрыть или через function.php в вашей тема.
Но сайдбары обычно с виджетов редактируются зайдите через консоль в виджеты и выберите определенные посты там.
Так же есть куча плагинов которые могут быть выборщиками постов по категории или другим параметрам.
Консоль -> Внешний вид -> Виджеты