# Как вывести иконку <i class=""> вместо текста "Войдите чтобы добавить коммент " в wordpress теме?

Tags: wordpress, wp-theme

запись для гостя выглядит так и в ней наезжает текст, особенно на русском. хотел бы поставить иконку и одно слово Login, чтобы умещалось.
[image: вот как сейчас выглядит]
но не выходит, в шаблоне видимо прописан стандартный вариант вывода этого текста, потому что шаблон сам не переведен и это заметно по другим частям шаблона. и только этот момент переводится на русский, т.к. комментирования закрыто неавторизованным.

код записей entry.php

```html
<?php
/**
 * Displays the content and meta information for a post object.
 *
 * @package P2
 */
?>
<li id="prologue-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
 <?php

 /*
  * Post meta
  */

 if ( ! is_page() ):
  $author_posts_url = get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) );
  $posts_by_title   = sprintf(
   __( 'Posts by %1$s ( @%2$s )', 'p2' ),
   get_the_author_meta( 'display_name' ),
   get_the_author_meta( 'user_nicename' )
  ); ?>

  <a href="<?php echo esc_attr( $author_posts_url ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( $posts_by_title ); ?>" class="post-avatar">
   <?php echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta('user_email'), 48 ); ?>
  </a>
 <?php endif; ?>
 <h4>
  <?php if ( ! is_page() ): ?>
   <a href="<?php echo esc_attr( $author_posts_url ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( $posts_by_title ); ?>"><?php the_author(); ?></a>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <span class="meta">
   <?php
   if ( ! is_page() ) {
    echo p2_date_time_with_microformat();
   } ?>
   <span class="actions">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="thepermalink<?php if ( is_singular() ) { ?> printer-only<?php } ?>" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Permalink', 'p2' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Permalink', 'p2' ); ?></a>
    <?php
    if ( ! is_singular() )
     $before_reply_link = ' | ';

    if ( comments_open() && ! post_password_required() ) {
      echo post_reply_link( array(
       'before'        => isset( $before_reply_link ) ? $before_reply_link : '',
       'after'         => '',
       'reply_text'    => __( 'Reply', 'p2' ),
       'add_below'     => 'comments'
      ), get_the_ID() );
    }

    if ( current_user_can( 'edit_post', get_the_ID() ) ) : ?> | <a href="<?php echo ( get_edit_post_link( get_the_ID() ) ); ?>" class="edit-post-link" rel="<?php the_ID(); ?>" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Edit', 'p2' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Edit', 'p2' ); ?></a>
    <?php endif; ?>

   <?php do_action( 'p2_action_links' ); ?>
   
   </span>
   <?php if ( is_object_in_taxonomy( get_post_type(), 'post_tag' ) ) : ?>
    <span class="tags">
     <?php tags_with_count( '', __( '<br />Tags:' , 'p2' ) .' ', ', ', ' &nbsp;' ); ?>&nbsp;
    </span>
   <?php endif; ?>
  </span>
 </h4>

 <?php
 /*
  * Content
  */
 ?>

 <div id="content-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="postcontent">
 <?php
 /*
  * Check the post format and display content accordingly.
  * The value should be a valid post format or one of the back compat categories.
  */
 switch ( p2_get_post_format( $post->ID ) ) {
  case 'status':
  case 'link':
   the_content( __( '(More ...)' , 'p2' ) );
   break;
  case 'quote':
   p2_quote_content();
   break;
  case 'post':
  case 'standard':
  default:
   p2_title();
   the_content( __( '(More ...)' , 'p2' ) );
   break;
 } ?>
 </div>

 <?php
 /*
  * Comments
  */

 $comment_field = '<div class="form"><textarea id="comment" class="expand50-100" name="comment" cols="45" rows="3"></textarea></div> <label class="post-error" for="comment" id="commenttext_error"></label>';

 $comment_notes_before = '<p class="comment-notes">' . ( get_option( 'require_name_email' ) ? sprintf( ' ' . __( 'Required fields are marked %s', 'p2' ), '<span class="required">*</span>' ) : '' ) . '</p>';

 $p2_comment_args = array(
  'title_reply'           => __( 'Reply', 'p2' ),
  'comment_field'         => $comment_field,
  'comment_notes_before'  => $comment_notes_before,
  'comment_notes_after'   => '<span class="progress spinner-comment-new"></span>',
  'label_submit'          => __( 'Reply', 'p2' ),
  'id_submit'             => 'comment-submit',
 );

 ?>

 <?php if ( get_comments_number() > 0 && ! post_password_required() ) : ?>
  <div class="discussion" style="display: none">
   <p>
    <?php p2_discussion_links(); ?>
    <a href="#" class="show-comments"><?php _e( 'Toggle Comments', 'p2' ); ?></a>
   </p>
  </div>
 <?php endif;

 wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<p class="page-nav">' . __( 'Pages:', 'p2' ) ) ); ?>

 <div class="bottom-of-entry">&nbsp;</div>

 <?php if ( p2_is_ajax_request() ) : ?>
  <ul id="comments-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="commentlist inlinecomments"></ul>
 <?php else :
  comments_template();
  $pc = 0;
  if ( p2_show_comment_form() && $pc == 0 && ! post_password_required() ) :
   $pc++; ?>
   <div class="respond-wrap" <?php echo ( ! is_singular() ) ? 'style="display: none; "' : ''; ?>>
    <?php comment_form( $p2_comment_args ); ?>
   </div><?php
  endif;
 endif; ?>
</li>
```

Comment: Вы не тот файл привели вообще. Скорее всего, нужный текст выводится в `p2_show_comment_form()`

Comment: Почитайте вот этот мой ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/798707/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2-wordpress/798849#798849 Найдите стили, выводимые рядом с нужным текстом. Стили не меняются при выводе, поэтому удобнее всего именно их искать в файлах php

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой способ найти решение, не зная какой код отвечает за вывод этой надписи и не вникая в структуру темы ВП - это банальный поиск файла по содержимому.

Алгоритм такой. В папке темы вордпресс произвести поиск файлов, содержащих текст "Войдите, чтобы добавить комментарий". В результате поиска будет найден файл локализации. Т.е. подключаемый файл языка, где указаны переменные и присвоенные им строки с переводом. Найдите вашу строку ctrl+f и узнаете переменную, которая отвечает за вывод этой фразы в коде. Теперь два пути. Если надо просто изменить текст, то можно прям тут и изменить. Если нужно изменить логику вывода сообщения или ещё что изменить в самом коде. Тогда снова возвращаемся к поиску файла по содержимому и ищем все файлы, в которых есть ваша переменная локализации, которую вы нашли. Теперь смотрим в код и анализируем, какой именно файл нам нужен и что нужно изменить. Из личного опыта.

Comment: из личного опыта это настолько простой способ, что я его знаю, и совпадений не найдено. в том и проблема. НО. из личного опыта вскрывая исходный код через браузер я просто ищу класс где рядом стоит внедрение комментов. и это вот этот код , начиная с <?php
 /*
  * Comments
  */

 $comment_field = '<div class="form"> код идет. что я выше указал полностью только. но там вообще не совпадает текст даже с иностранной версией его. так что ни то что русская локализация даже по английской не то.

Comment: все это отображается если юзер авторизован. а вот где текст который видно при закрытии гостевого комментария. мне не понятно.

Comment: Тут `reply_text' => __( 'Reply', 'p2' ),` пробовали менять на свой текст вместо reply ? И возвращаясь к поиску, если этот текст есть на странице, значит он где-то лежит. Слабо верится что он генерится динамически. Возможно он подхватывается из БД? Сделайте дамп БД и там тоже можно поискать. Это же текст)) должно найти. Попробуйте расширить поиск. Ищите по начальному слову. Я бы так попробовал.

Comment: Послушай добрый совет - не зная ВП - промолчи, не отвечай. Ибо ересь несёшь.

Comment: Чтоб изменить вывод текста на сайте всенепременно необходимо знать ВП. О как,. ну ладно, пойду тогда учить

Comment: Именно!  Не нужно ничего искать. Достаточно знать, где находятся файлы локализации. И менять тексты в файлах - зло.