# Как мне исправить теги H1 в body сайта на Wordpress-е?

Tags: wordpress

У меня есть сайт https://glpatios.com/

Он создан на теме Wordpress-а "Creativity"
Главная страница у него не ститическая, оно генерится движком сайта.
В теле сайта  есть аж четыре H1 тега, а допустимо - один.

Я хочу исправить это, но не могу найти, где находятся эти четыре H1 тега, чтобы я мог их изменить.
Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/798707/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2-wordpress/798849#798849

Comment: У вас три слайда, два из них не отображаются. Каждый слайд имеет h1. Убирайте ненужные слайды. А четвертый h1 у вас в каком-то скрипте, где не скрипт даже, а просто html с текстом Drop files to upload. Попробуйте понять, откуда это, или делайте поиск по файлам.

Comment: @KAGGDesign Спасибо большое! А как мне удалить ненужные слайды. Я не могу их найти. Где они?

Comment: Разбирайтесь с темой, у меня ее нет. Все должно быть в админке, по идее

Answer (score 0):

Тема на билдере работает?
Если нет - ищите в директории темы файлы типа front-page.php, index.php, page.php и т.п.
Не зная структуры темы, ответить очень сложно.

Если на билдере - то пробуйте использовать другие компоненты и искать настройки самого билдера, в которых указывается тип заголовка.